# Wagtail preview keeps asking to accept cookies

Tags: wagtail

Wagtail preview keeps asking one of our users to accept cookies, even though we have switched the SESSION_ENGINE to use the Redis Cache rather than the Signed Cookies

The user is using a DELL laptop, connecting via Citrix and is using the Chrome browser

Does not happen for me when I edit the same Wagtail page

Comment: This is occurring even if the user sets "Allow all cookies" in the Chrome browser

Comment: This is only happening on our prod site and not dev or uat and only for certain users